# My menu isnt responsive, what am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

### My responsive menu gives me problems.

"Audiences" should disappear and appear in the drop down menu, why does it come out like this?

I have to make "hearings" appear in the drop-down menu and disappear from there. So, can someone please fix my problem with below the code ?

[image]
[image]

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

   <a href="udienze.php" class="active">Udienze</a>
      <a href="udienze-del-giorno.php" >Udienze di Oggi </a>
  <a href="../appuntamenti/appuntamenti.php">Appuntamenti</a>
  <a href="../appuntamenti/appuntamenti-del-giorno.php">Appuntamenti di Oggi</a>
    <a href="../../index.php">Torna al menu principale</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>

  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like you have some javascript missing as there are missed references to functions.

Comment: function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to debug the problem? And how is this related to PHP?

Comment: it is not related to php, i was wrong. I can't solve this problem, I would just have to make "hearings" go below and not return to the topnav bar when I click on the drop down menu

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume it's because of this line of code right here:

```css
.topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

You're calling `:not(:first-child)` which means that you want all of your `.topnav a` elements **except** the first child to have the style defined. Changing that section to this worked for me when replicating your issue.

```css
.topnav a {
  display: none;
}
```

[image: Edit Responsive Menu]

Comment: Yes, thanks, but it remains for me that when I click it continues to stay on, why?

Comment: Going to need a little more code to help with that. I need to say how your function is setup and what you do with your responsive menu.

Comment: what I posted is all the code, only the javascript is missing:
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

Comment: Checkout the sandbox link. I'm going to assume that's what you were looking for?